# Google Cloud quotas in us-east4 are very limiting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Any new project that we start has very restrictive quotas for `us-east4` - e.g. 24 CPUs

While most quota increase requests seem to be approved immediately, the requests are manual. Because our workflow involves automatically spinning up projects, we need an solution that doesn't involve manual intervention

In comparison, the same project has more reasonable quotas for other regions - e.g. 2400 CPUs for `us-west1`, `us-east1`, `us-central1`

Is there something about `us-east4` that makes it inappropriate for these sorts of workloads? We're using it because of lower latency to us, but will be flexible if absolutely required

[image: quotas for new project]

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP quota [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) users have to proactively [request a quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#request_quotas). In that case you can request a quota increase that will take into account your expected upcoming increase in usage. A [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/73528905) has been created so that this functionality can be made available in the future. Right now there is not an ETA for this FR but any progress can be tracked on the previous link.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this doesn't address the question. "Because our workflow involves automatically spinning up projects, we need an solution that doesn't involve manual intervention"

Comment: A Feature Request was created for this functionality to be made available in the future: https://issuetracker.google.com/73528905.                     Right now there is not an ETA for this FR but any progress can be tracked on the previous link